# site looping redirection in apache2

Tags: virtualhost, apache2

Here is a [site](https://siral.marketing) i recently tried to setup.. when i try to access it for some reason it always redirects back and forth www to non www without end. Here is my apache2 virtual host.. i really can't figure out why this is happening.. i only set the A record to point to my server IP address

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerAdmin aditya@siral.marketing
    ServerName siral.marketing
    ServerAlias www.siral.marketing
    DocumentRoot /var/www/smartpanel

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    <Directory /var/www/smartpanel>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Require all granted
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `siral.marketing` has two IP addresses:

```
$ dig siral.marketing +short
192.64.119.69
23.229.5.114
```

- The web server on `23.229.5.114` is the Apache web server you are referring to, and has the same IP address than the `www.siral.marketing`. That web server works sensibly, redirecting `http://www.siral.marketing` to `http://siral.marketing` and responding with the web page there.
- The other web server on `192.64.119.69` is a *Namecheap URL Forward*, an Nginx server performing the opposite redirection:

  ```
  * Connected to siral.marketing (192.64.119.69) port 80 (#0)
  > GET / HTTP/1.1
  > Host: siral.marketing
  > User-Agent: curl/7.64.0
  > Accept: */*
  >
  < HTTP/1.1 302 Found
  < Server: nginx
  < Date: Sat, 30 May 2020 21:08:01 GMT
  < Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
  < Content-Length: 50
  < Connection: keep-alive
  < Location: http://www.siral.marketing/
  < X-Served-By: Namecheap URL Forward
  <
  <a href='http://www.siral.marketing/'>Found</a>.
  ```

Removing the bogus `A` record (and/or disabling the Namecheap URL Forwarding) will solve the problem.